# listen-ip is going for default

Tags: cpp-ethereum, bug

listen ip option in cpp-ethereum always takes default address 0.0.0.0 not the one we specify.

I give the following command

```
$./eth --upnp off --listen-ip 127.0.0.1
```

output is

> cpp-ethereum, a C++ Ethereum client
>
> cpp-ethereum 1.3.0    By cpp-ethereum contributors, (c) 2013-2016.
>   See the README for contributors and credits.
>
> Transaction Signer: XE893RTKL7TK90RQSR0JDUW5981HUK0HZ0
>   (2128dfc7-a653-26ff-4648-8cb224b7ed84 - 00e5ad83)
>
> Mining Beneficiary: XE893RTKL7TK90RQSR0JDUW5981HUK0HZ0
>   (2128dfc7-a653-26ff-4648-8cb224b7ed84 - 00e5ad83) Foundation:
>   XE55PXQKKK4B9BYPBGT1XCYW6R5ELFAT6EM
>   (00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 - de0b2956)
>
> Node ID:
>   enode://f234d190c693fcc1ed8b13720fc3cee794b6579a35667af707b2cdab311bff4555f7022915f1a2a28da7d583ea9dacdff4e99b68bcfa243b1999c007ca62f601@**0.0.0.0**:10303
>
> JSONRPC Admin Session Key: N/sibgczkwQ=
>
> Port numbers are getting changed not the ip address. \
>
> In main.cpp, there is no default 0.0.0.0 initalized for listenIP.

What is the solution for this?

Comment: This looks like a bug worth reporting on github.